# For Loops in Python (Output Smallest Input)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Okay so I am practicing for loops in  Python and I was wondering how could I make a user input 10 intergers then it would output the smallest one. I would know how to do this with a while loop for example:

```
Smallest = 0
count = 0
while count < 10:
    Number = int(input("Enter a number >> "))
    if Number < Smallest:
        Smallest = Number
    count = count + 1

print("{0} is the biggest value you have entered".format(Smallest))
```

But how do I do it in a for loop format? Here's what I have so far:

```
for i in range(10):
    Number = int(input("Enter a Number >> "))
    if Number < Smallest:
        Smallest = Number

print("{0} is the smallest value you have entered.".format(Smallest))
```

Comment: `min(int(input("Enter a Number >> ")) for  i in range(10))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands you should definitely give that as an answer instead of a comment, cause it looks really slick :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there, other than the fact you should initialise `Smallest`, is equivalent to the solution using your `while` statement.

So, assuming the `while` variant is considered correct, the `for` variant you have will suffice.

The reason I qualify it is because initialising `Smallest` to zero is actually the *wrong* thing to do. If your ten numbers are all greater than twenty (for example), `Smallest` will remain at zero, giving you the wrong answer.

One way to fix this (in both variants) is to change your `if` statement to:

```
if i == 0 or Number < Smallest:
```

which will set `Smallest` first time through the loop regardless (though it should be `count` in the `while` variant since that's using a different loop control variable).

---

Of course, as you learn more and more about the language, you'll come across the concept of things that are more "Pythonic" than others. An example of this is the rather more succinct:

```
Smallest = min(int(input("Enter a Number >> ")) for i in range(10))
```

which removes the need totally for an explicit check-and-replace strategy (that's still done, but under the covers of the `min` function).

Comment: I want to use a for loop though?

Comment: @Sam, I'm *telling* you to use the `for` loop, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your Smallest variable and all will works!

```
Smallest = int(input("Enter a Number >> "))
for i in range(9):
    Number = int(input("Enter a Number >> "))
    if Number < Smallest:
        Smallest = Number

print("{0} is the smallest value you have entered.".format(Smallest))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the smallest of the input numbers, you need to start with a minimum a bit bigger than 0... and that is a problem you have with your while loop. It will only work if the user inputs at least one negative number, else it will return `0`.

Here is what I suggest:

```
smallest = float("inf")
for i in range(10):
    number = int(input("Enter a Number >> "))
    if number < smallest:
        smallest = number
print("{0} is the smallest value you have entered.".format(smallest))
```

Note that I did not capitalize the variables, because to me it makes them look like classes. ^^

Comment: A class is something used in Object Oriented Programming. If you do not know what it is, don't worry. You do not need to use OOP in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are finding the Smallest values out of the input values from the user it is good practice to initially initialize the Smallest variable as maximum possible integer as below.

```
import sys
Smallest = sys.maxint
```

Then the rest of your loop will work as properly as it is.

Comment: That's a good answer for Python 2 but the bracketed `print` in the question tends to indicate Python 3. There, `maxint` no longer exists, nor does the arbitrary limit on what an `int` can hold. It might be worth pointing that out.

Comment: yeah.. thanks for pointing out. I didn't noticed the brackets. In this case sys.maxsize can also be used in its place.

Comment: Almost: `maxsize` will give you the "natural" limit (such as `2^64 - 1`) but the removal of arbitrary limits on integer types means you can have values greater than this - try `import sys`, `x = sys.maxsize`, `print(x)`, `print(x+1)` to see this problem. In other words, the user entering all values greater than `maxsize` will not work so well, since the result will be `maxsize`.